# What is the probability that a given random sub-sequence of length $M$ is present in the first sequence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This should be a simple combinatorial problem, but every time I try to solve it I come up with a different formula.  It is NOT a homework problem, I'm just trying to understand some aspects of immunology.

Question:  Given a first sequence of $L$ characters randomly selected from an alphabet of $N$ characters, what is the probability that a given random sub-sequence of length $M$ is present in the first sequence?

For example, given the alphabet of characters {A,B,C,D},
and a first sequence of randomly selected characters of length 10: $$(char1,char2,char3,char4,char5,char6,char7,char8,char9,char10),$$
and a given contiguous subsequence of 3 characters (B,A,A),

then what is the probability that the given contiguous sequence (B,A,A) occurs in the first sequence?

The following first sequence would contain two instances of the given contiguous subsequence:  $$ (A,B,A,A,C,B,A,A,D,A).$$

It feels as if the answer should be $\left(\frac {n-1} n \right)^M (L-M+1)$, but I don't believe the numbers I get.

Re-Edit: My latest try is this:  The first character in the first sequence should have a probability  $$P1 = 1-\left(\frac {N-1} N \right) $$ of being the first character of the subsequence. Same should be true of the second character, third, etc.  So, the probability that the first M characters of the first sequence are the given subsequence should be $$P2 = (1-\left(\frac {N-1} N \right))^M .$$

But there are $(L-M+1) different locations along the first sequence where the subsequence might occur, so the probability that it occurs at *none* of those locations should be $$P3 = (1-P1)^{(L-M+1)}. $$

If that's right, then the probability that there *is* a match of the subsequence somewhere along the first sequence should be $$ (1-P3) $$ or 
$$1-(1-P1)^{(L-M+1)},  $$
or $$1-(1- (1-\left(\frac {N-1} N \right))^M )^{(L-M+1)},  $$

Is this correct?  The numbers still don't seem believable.

Comment: What is a "given random sub-sequence"? A given subsequence is fixed, is it not? How can it be random?

Comment: Whether it is homework or not, is not the point.  You should be adding more details, e.g., why do you "feel" the answer should be what you feel they should be, and why don't you believe the numbers you get.  Show those numbers, and your work to get them, and explain why you "feel" what you say you "feel" should be the case.

Comment: @uniquesolution : I doubt the word "random" was intended in the sense of probability theory. I would take it to mean "arbitrary", i.e. it doesn't matter which one it is.

Comment: Where you wronte $\dfrac{n-1} n,$ did you mean $\dfrac{N-1} N \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy -- I doubt it too. However, the word 'random' is viciously overloaded in that one sentence. Its first use is 'randomly', in a strict mathematical sense. The second use is simply bad English. All I can do is just repeat Alice's question to Humpty Dumpty: Can one word have so many meanings?

Comment: Note that $M=1$ and $M=L$ are simple subproblems you can solve separately.  Does your assumed answer agree with them?

Comment: If this is an immunology question, can you confirm that the subsequence is a mathematical subsequence, ie the characters don't have to be in order? It strikes me that something like DNA would probably have to be continuous to be relevant, but I'm not sure what the context is. Sorry for speaking from left field otherwise...

Comment: The characters MUST be in order.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you edit the problem to include a couple of examples of what you want to compute in general, using *small* numbers for $L$, $M$, and $N$, where you can compute everything explicitly. For one thing, this provides the first "sanity check" that any proposed general formula must satisfy. It can also help clarify the precise meaning of the question (e.g., what it means for a "given" sequence to be "random").

Comment: OK, I re-edited.  Also came up with a formula that feels properly reasoned out, but doesn't give me a lot of confidence!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{L!(N-M)!}{(L-M)!N!}$  This assumes the two sequences are independent and $M\le L$.  The general idea is that the first of $M$ has a probability of $\frac{L}{N}$ of being among $L$.  The next of $M$ has a probability of $\frac{L-1}{N-1}$, since one item has been chosen from $L$ (and $N$), etc.

Comment: I don't expect any factorials in the correct expression because the problem doesn't involve permutations.  A first sequence with an arbitrary string of characters gggklmtbvvgx is valid, as is any arbitrary string of characters in the subsequence.

Comment: @S.McGrew I had assumed all the characters were different.  If there are repeats the answer is more complicated.  Your expanded description is quite different from what I had assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Where you wrote $\dfrac{n-1}n,$ I will assume here that you meant $\dfrac{N-1} N.$

This will be at most a partial answer.

Suppose the subsequence is $\text{CAT}.$ One could have
$$
\text{PQRSA }\underline{\textbf{C}} \text{ TYRUIS } \underline{\textbf{A}} \text{ JGHKF }\underline{\textbf{T}} \text{ ZSD}
$$
The letters $\text{CAT}$ are in positions $6,$ $13,$ and $19.$

First one must choose in which positions to put the sequence $\text{CAT}.$ There are $\dbinom{22}3$ ways to do that in a sequence of length $22.$

Then one must ask what is the probability that the letters in those positions are $\text{CAT}.$

Then multiply and get an approximation to the probability if that sequence occurs rarely.

HOWEVER, the probability differs that, since $\text{CAT}$ may appear more than once. If that sequence appears rarely, then that is improbable, so the approximation found above may be close.

Comment: I think it might be simpler than that.  Please see my edit.